# Changing SSL certificates on the fly in IdHTTPServer

Tags: delphi, ssl, ssl-certificate, pascal, indy

I'm developing a **MITM proxy with SSL** support in delphi 10.3, using indy. I use **IdHttpServer** component, which does work in **CommandOther** event. I managed to make it to decrypt and dump data on the fly, and reencrypt and send it to browser, but I need to change idhttpserver certificate for each domain. I can generate them and install my own CA, but i cant find a way to change them **while my proxy is working**. I will greatly appreciate if someone will show me how!

```
 procedure TForm3.IdHTTPServer1CommandOther(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
 var
S: string;
LClient: TIdtcpClient;
 newsize:int64;
LBuf: TIdBytes;
Len: Integer;

var response:integer;
s3: TStringDynArray;
var cmd:string;
bytes:tidbytes;

oldstr,newstr:string;
ResponseCode, ResponseText: string;
  Size: Int64;
ssl:tIdServerIOHandlerSSLopenssl;


begin
 if not TextIsSame(ARequestInfo.Command, 'CONNECT') then Exit;


 LClient := TIdtcpClient.Create(nil);
  try

S := ARequestInfo.URI;
LClient.Host := Fetch(S, ':', True);
LClient.Port := StrToIntDef(S, 443);


LClient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(LClient);


LClient.ConnectTimeout := 5000;



// connect and activate SSL between this proxy and the target server

LClient.Connect;
try
  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
  AResponseInfo.ResponseText := 'Connection established';
  AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;


  // activate SSL between this proxy and the client
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(AContext.Connection.Socket).PassThrough:=false;

  // pass data between AContext.Connection.IOHandler and LClient.IOHandler
//as needed.


  // received data will be decrypted, and sent data will be encryted...
  while AContext.Connection.Connected and lclient.Connected do
  begin

    //mitm traffic modification routine      


  end;

finally

 LClient.Disconnect;

end;
 finally
 LClient.Free;

end;
 end;
```

This is cert switching code:

```
procedure TForm3.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var

SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin

if AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port = 443 then
        begin



sslh:=tIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);



          sslh.SSLOptions.CertFile:='Certificate.pem';
     sslh.SSLOptions.keyfile:='PrivateKey.pem';
    sslh.SSLOptions.RootCertFile:='certificateAuthorityCertificate.pem';
     sslh.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:=[sslvSSLv23];
     sslh.ssloptions.mode:=sslmBoth;
   sslh.OnGetPassword:= IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1GetPassword;

     sslh.PassThrough:=false;

      TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(AContext.Connection).PassThrough:=false;
       //memo2.Text:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();

        end;

  end;
```

On a form I have a tidhttpserver and TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL as iohandler for it.

Answer (score 3):

Assign on `OnQuerySSLPort` event handler that unconditionally sets the `VUseSSL` parameter to `False` regardless of the `APort` requested. Then, in the `OnConnect` event, if the `AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port` property is 443 (or whatever port you want to use HTTPS on), you can typecast the `AContext.Connection.IOHandler` property to  `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` (or descendant, like `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` if using OpenSSL), configure its certificates as needed, and then set its `PassThrough` property to `False` to complete the SSL/TLS handshake.

Comment: Thanks Remy! thats a routine i use in OnConnect event after i check for port, but it doesn't work, page just not loading and getting Secure Connection failed inf FF right away
  `sslh:=  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;`
  `AContext.Connection.IOHandler:= sslh;`
   `sslh.SSLOptions.CertFile:='Certificate.pem'; `
   `sslh.SSLOptions.keyfile:='PrivateKey.pem';`
   `sslh.SSLOptions.RootCertFile:='AuthorityCertificate.pem';`
   `sslh.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:=[sslvTLSv1_2];`
   `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(AContext.Connection).PassThrough:=false;`

Comment: @JoshSterling when setting the `PassThrough`, you are typecasting the `Connection` object, not its `IOHandler` object. You could have just used `sslh.PassThrough` instead. But you don't need to create a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object manually as the server does that for you if you have `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` assigned to the server's `IOHandler`, just typecast the existing client `IOHandler`, eg: `sslh := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(AContext.Connection.IOHandler);`

Comment: with code above if PassThrough set to true it works with cert set in TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL but with PassThrough set to  False it doesnt let to connect, FF says authenticity of the received data could not be verified. I feel like i just don't understand how the whole thing supposed to work, but cant find any good examples for fast certs switching

Comment: @JoshSterling then please update your question to include the actual code you are having trouble with

Comment: done. i included your code too. On CommandOther event my proxy decrypts and modifies traffic

Comment: i worked on this a bit more and noticed, after i set sshl:=false, code doesn't continue to execute @Remy-Lebeau